# tuple error orrured while looping the code for each csv files

Tags: python, integer, tuples, slice

```
T = ('twang10_1.csv','twang10_2.csv','twang10_3.csv','twang12_1.csv','twang12_2.csv','twang12_3.csv','twang14_1.csv','twang14_2.csv','twang14_3.csv','1000.csv','500.csv','voice.csv')

file_in = []

for item in T:
    file_in.append(open(item, 'r'))

y = T[1].to_numpy() for this line i get the error
```

for each csv files in the variable T i need to produce a graph for each file. but i get tuple must be integers error.
saying: tuple indices must be integers or slices, not str

Comment: `T[1]` is the string "twang10_2.csv".  Strings don't have a `to_numpy()` method.  I don't see how this code can possibly have the error you say...

Answer (score 1):

You're calling the wrong list here. To make a graph based on the data in the CSV, you want to call the file_in[1] (second item in the list) not T[1], as this is just a string with the name of the CSV.

```py
T = ('twang10_1.csv','twang10_2.csv','twang10_3.csv','twang12_1.csv','twang12_2.csv','twang12_3.csv','twang14_1.csv','twang14_2.csv','twang14_3.csv','1000.csv','500.csv','voice.csv')

file_in = []

for item in T:
    file_in.append(open(item, 'r'))

y = file_in[1].to_numpy() #for this line i get the error
```

This will call the file data, not the file name.

```py
import numpy as np

T = ('twang10_1.csv','twang10_2.csv','twang10_3.csv','twang12_1.csv','twang12_2.csv','twang12_3.csv','twang14_1.csv','twang14_2.csv','twang14_3.csv','1000.csv','500.csv','voice.csv')

numpy_list= []

for item in T:
    numpy_list.append(np.loadtxt(item, delimiter=","))

#Every item in numpy_list would then be a numpy array
```

NumPy load array from CSV youtube video: https://youtu.be/Z2unXTrGp04

Based on comment discussion:

```py
import numpy as np 
#import pandas as pd #Pandas is not used here, not needed
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
#from scipy import signal #not sure if you need this later on, but it's not needed in this snippit. 

sampling_rate=5000
sampling_time=0.1 

T = ('twang10_1.csv','twang10_2.csv','twang10_3.csv','twang12_1.csv','twang12_2.csv','twang12_3.csv','twang14_1.csv','twang14_2.csv','twang14_3.csv','1000.csv','500.csv','voice.csv')

csv_data = [] 

for item in T: 
    csv_data.append(np.loadtxt(item, delimiter=","))

y = csv_data[1] 



y_av = np.average(y) 

start_value = np.argmax(y) 

end_value = int(start_value+sampling_time*sampling_rate) 
#y = y - y_av 
#you can't subtract a value from a list of values

#y = y[start_value:end_value] 
#not needed

x = np.linspace(0, len(y)/sampling_rate, len(y)) 

fig, ax1 = plt.subplots() #fig is not being used, can be left out

plot = ax1.scatter(x,y,s=1,color='red') #plt can't be set to a value as it's a module import, can't use it in multiple ways

ax1.set_xlabel("time (s)") 

ax1.set_ylabel("amplitude")
```

I believe this will work for you, I've explained what I changed and why in the comments in the code.

```py
import numpy as np 
#import pandas as pd #Pandas is not used here, not needed
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
#from scipy import signal #not sure if you need this later on, but it's not needed in this snippit. 

sampling_rate=5000
sampling_time=0.1 

T = ('twang10_1.csv','twang10_2.csv','twang10_3.csv','twang12_1.csv','twang12_2.csv','twang12_3.csv','twang14_1.csv','twang14_2.csv','twang14_3.csv','1000.csv','500.csv','voice.csv')

#csv_data = [] Not needed if you're just wanting a graph, and not worrying about manipulating the data otherwise. 

for item in T:
    y = np.loadtxt(item, delimiter=",")
    y_av = np.average(y) 
    start_value = np.argmax(y) 
    end_value = int(start_value+sampling_time*sampling_rate) 
    #y = y - y_av 
    #you can't subtract a value from a list of values
    #y = y[start_value:end_value] 
    #not needed
    x = np.linspace(0, len(y)/sampling_rate, len(y)) 
    fig, ax1 = plt.subplots() #fig is not being used, can be left out
    plot = ax1.scatter(x,y,s=1,color='red') #plt can't be set to a value as it's a module import, can't use it in multiple ways
    ax1.set_xlabel("time (s)") 
    ax1.set_ylabel("amplitude")
```

This one will loop and do a graph for every csv file.

Comment: hi thank you so much for answering! I have done that and now i get another error saying '_io.TextIOWrapper' object has no attribute 'to_numpy'

Comment: also i set the first row of all csv files to 1 so it can read the entire column to put it as numpy but it says it has no attribute 'to_numpy'

Comment: So I'm not sure if you're using Pandas or just straight NumPy, but with .to_numpy(), that is part of the Pandas module, when coming from a dataframe. To get a CSV to a NumPy array, you'd first need to import it at the top of your file:
import numpy as np # as np just gives it a nickname so you can call it easier. 

then open it via numpy

array1 = np.loadtxt("twang10_1.csv", delimiter=",")

And that'd get you your numpy array. 
If using Pandas, you'd need to load the CSV into a dataframe first, then use the .to_numpy() function from Pandas to convert it to NumPy array.

Comment: import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy import signal 

T = (np.array('twang10_1.csv'),....)

file_in = []
for item in T:
    file_in.append(open(item, 'r'))
y = file_in[1]
sampling_rate=5000

y_av=np.average(y)
y=y-y_av

start_value=np.argmax(y)
sampling_time=0.1
end_value=int(start_value+sampling_time*sampling_rate)
y=y[start_value:end_value]

x=np.linspace(0, len(y)/sampling_rate, len(y))

fig, ax1=plt.subplots() 
plt=ax1.scatter(x,y,s=1,color='red')
ax1.set_xlabel("time (s)")
ax1.set_ylabel("amplitude")

Comment: this is the part of the code to produce 12 graphs for each csv files... i imported pd and np and i just want the code to read the actual numbers in the csv files!

Comment: I've updated my answer with what I think you're looking for.

Comment: it's going somehwere! thank you very much. it's just that it's not repeating for each csv files now :(

Comment: This one should get you through every CSV file.

Comment: you are a legend now i can sleep at 4 am thank you so much!!!!!!